# loop through an array of objects to search for origin -> destination and destination -> origin and pull counts

Tags: javascript, arrays, find

I have an array of objects with origin and destination information, showing the total volume of objects traveling from one place to another.
I'm trying to compare the counts of flows between two cities. For instance, below, when the origin is Vancouver and the destination is San Francisco, the count is 5, but when it's reversed (the origin is San Francisco and the destination is Vancouver) the count is 12.

```
    InOut = [
      {
        "origin": "Pittsburgh, Pennsylvania",
        "dest": "New York, New York",
        "count": 5
      },
      {
        "origin": "Pittsburgh, Pennsylvania",
        "dest": "Newark, New Jersey",
        "count": 2
      },
      {
        "origin": "Los Angeles, California",
        "dest": "Seattle, Washington",
        "count": 6
      },
      {
        "origin": "Vancouver, Canada",
        "dest": "Brooklyn, New York",
        "count": 3
      },
      {
        "origin": "Detroit, Michigan",
        "dest": "New York, New York",
        "count": 4
      },
      {
        "origin": "Detroit, Michigan",
        "dest": "Washington, DC",
        "count": 11
      },
      {
        "origin": "Vancouver, Canada",
        "dest": "San Francisco, California",
        "count": 5
      },
      {
        "origin": "New York, New York",
        "dest": "Pittsburgh, Pennsylvania",
        "count": 9
      },
      {
        "origin": "New York, New York",
        "dest": "Detroit, Michigan",
        "count": 7
      },
      {
        "origin": "Philadelphia, Pennsylvania",
        "dest": "Baltimore, Maryland",
        "count": 12
      },
      {
        "origin": "Philadelphia, Pennsylvania",
        "dest": "New York, New York",
        "count": 6
      },
      {
        "origin": "Seattle, Washington",
        "dest": "Los Angeles, California",
        "count": 3
      },
      {
        "origin": "San Francisco, California",
        "dest": "Vancouver, Canada",
        "count": 12
      }
    ]
```

I know I could look up the counts based on the origins and destinations like this:

```
    function findValueByKey(array, key, value, key2, value2) {
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i][key] == value && array[i][key2] == value2) {
                return array[i].count;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    var obj = findValueByKey(InOut, 'origin', 'Vancouver, Canada', 'dest', 'San Francisco, California');
    var obj2 = findValueByKey(InOut, 'origin', 'San Francisco, California', 'dest', 'Vancouver, Canada');
    console.log('obj', obj)
    console.log('obj', obj2)
```

However, I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to loop through the array to get all of the counts. This is as far as I've come:

```
    allLocations = ["Pittsburgh, Pennsylvania", "Los Angeles, California", "Newark, New Jersey", "Seattle, Washington", "Vancouver, Canada", "Brooklyn, New York", "Detroit, Michigan", "Washington, DC", "New York, New York", "Philadelphia, Pennsylvania", "San Francisco, California"]

    origDestValues = []
    for(i=0; i< allLocations.length;i++){
      InOutA = findValueByKey(setOne, 'origin', allLocations[i], 'dest', allLocations[i])
      InOutB = findValueByKey(setOne, 'origin', allLocations[i], 'dest', allLocations[i])
      origDestValues.push({
          city1: allLocations[i],
          city2: allLocations[i],
          firstCount: InOutA,
          secondCount: InOutB
      });
    };
```

Obviously that wouldn't work since it would look for the same origin/destination every time, but I think this is headed in the right direction? I wanted to show proof that I've put some effort into it before asking here.

Also, for what it's worth, my actual array is much longer (many more cities). I've simplified it for the purpose of this question.

Thank you for any/all help.

Comment: Hey @sprucegoose, is my answer giving you what you wanted?

Comment: @IvanD Awesome, thank you! I appreciate your comments explaining the code. This is exactly what I was looking for and I've accepted your answer. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run this code to see the output:

```js
const inOut = [{
    "origin": "Pittsburgh, Pennsylvania",
    "dest": "New York, New York",
    "count": 5
  },
  {
    "origin": "Pittsburgh, Pennsylvania",
    "dest": "Newark, New Jersey",
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "origin": "Los Angeles, California",
    "dest": "Seattle, Washington",
    "count": 6
  },
  {
    "origin": "Vancouver, Canada",
    "dest": "Brooklyn, New York",
    "count": 3
  },
  {
    "origin": "Detroit, Michigan",
    "dest": "New York, New York",
    "count": 4
  },
  {
    "origin": "Detroit, Michigan",
    "dest": "Washington, DC",
    "count": 11
  },
  {
    "origin": "Vancouver, Canada",
    "dest": "San Francisco, California",
    "count": 5
  },
  {
    "origin": "New York, New York",
    "dest": "Pittsburgh, Pennsylvania",
    "count": 9
  },
  {
    "origin": "New York, New York",
    "dest": "Detroit, Michigan",
    "count": 7
  },
  {
    "origin": "Philadelphia, Pennsylvania",
    "dest": "Baltimore, Maryland",
    "count": 12
  },
  {
    "origin": "Philadelphia, Pennsylvania",
    "dest": "New York, New York",
    "count": 6
  },
  {
    "origin": "Seattle, Washington",
    "dest": "Los Angeles, California",
    "count": 3
  },
  {
    "origin": "San Francisco, California",
    "dest": "Vancouver, Canada",
    "count": 12
  }
]

// Step 1. Find all possible cities:
const cities = {}

// because we are using an object, we won't have any duplicates
for (const unit of inOut) {
  cities[unit.origin] = {}
  cities[unit.dest] = {}
}

// Step 2. Generate a matrix of all cities to all cities:
for (const city1 in cities) {
  for (const city2 in cities) {
    if (city1 !== city2) { // we don't need a dest == origin pair
      cities[city1][city2] = {
        to: 0,
        from: 0
      }
    }
  }
}

// Step 3. Populate the matrix twice: once for a destination and once for an origin:
for (const io of inOut) {
  cities[io.origin][io.dest].to += io.count
  cities[io.dest][io.origin].from += io.count
}

// Step 4. Optionally, we can remove empty pairs, where to and from are 0
for (const city1 in cities) {
  for (const city2 in cities[city1]) {
    if (cities[city1][city2].to === 0 && cities[city1][city2].from === 0) {
      delete cities[city1][city2]
    }
  }
}

console.log("List of all combinations:")
console.log(cities)

console.log("For example, info about one city (Pittsburgh, Pennsylvania) can be found like that:")
console.log(cities["Pittsburgh, Pennsylvania"])

console.log("For example, the flow between Pittsburgh, Pennsylvania and New York, New York can be found like that:")
console.log(cities["Pittsburgh, Pennsylvania"]["New York, New York"])

console.log("You can also chech the opposite direction (the flow between  and New York, New York and Pittsburgh, Pennsylvania):")
console.log(cities["New York, New York"]["Pittsburgh, Pennsylvania"])

console.log("Note that for a non-existant pair (there were no transactions), you'll get undefined:")
console.log(cities["Pittsburgh, Pennsylvania"]["Vancouver, Canada"])
```